# how to print N numbers multiples but change the value printed?

Tags: python

so I was given a problem where I have to write a program that the user has to give a positive integer number N and it has to print all numbers up to N but the multiples of 2 must be turned to EPL and multiples of 9 into 032 and for both multiples of 2 and 9 to give  EPL 032. I have trouble with the loops as I don't know how to put one into the other.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: There are not multiple loops.  There's one loop with several `if` conditions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.